# Macro for Copy/Paste Image in Tex file

Tags: macros, graphics, texstudio, conversion, automation

I am writing a document that has a lot of images which are basically extracts from other PDF's.

What I do now is to copy the image, paste it in MSPaint and then I save it in the path folder that I'm using for \includegraphics{path}.

Is there any way one can simply this extra work by copying the image and paste it directly into the editor from the clipboard? I'm sure there is no straight-forward way, but can there be any trick that would convert the path or the image to a \includegraphics command?

I have noticed that if one pastes an image which is in clipboard to the tex editor, nothing happens. Is there any way to at least convert that image to the file path?

I have drawn what I have in mind, but please correct me if I'm dreaming of unicorns:
[image: ![Macro Sketch]

Or does anyone know any faster way to do that? It sux when you have a lot of pictures.

EDIT: After reading the answers from Hamid I have realized that it is about setting up a Macro that:

1. Saves the image from the clipboard to a file
2. Reads the name and includes in a preset code (\begin{figure} \includegraphics{path_created_by_macro} \end{figure})
3. Writes this in the editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are working in Linux you can use a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `ls  ./myImageDIR/*.png;`
do
  echo '
  \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{'$f'}
  \end{figure}' 
done
```

and, following the tips in: [How to execute shell script from LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252957/how-to-execute-shell-script-from-latex), compile the file `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\immediate\write18{./my-shell-script.sh > scriptoutput.tex}
\begin{document}
\input{scriptoutput.tex}
\end{document}
```

with the command line:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -enable-write18 test.tex
```

If you need to add some text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
text ...
\immediate\write18{./InsertOneImageLatex.sh  firstPicture}
\input{firstPicture.tex}
...other text...
\immediate\write18{./InsertOneImageLatex.sh  SecondPicture}
\input{SecondPicture.tex}
\end{document}
```

with `InsertOneImageLatex.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '
\begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{'./myImageDIR/$1.png'}
\end{figure}' > $1.tex;
```

Comment: Okay. I just tried it. I get 
./Script.txt: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/Script.txt: line 3: `do

Comment: try to remove \r with: tr -d "\r" < Script.txt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134791/how-do-i-remove-newlines-from-a-text-file/3134827#3134827

Comment: Hmm. Weird. I tried both with "tr -d '\n' < yourfile.txt" and "tr -d "\n\r" < yourfile.txt", as recommended by Tyler... 

I get this after writing the code: #!/bin/bashfor f in 'ls  ./myImageDIR/*.png;'do  echo '  \begin{figure}        \includegraphics{'$f'}  \end{figure}' >> new.texdone

And after writing ./Script, I get the same error:
./Script.txt: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/Script.txt: line 3: `do

Comment: Probably it depends on how you save your script ... you should use Unix/Linux for 'Line ending'

Comment: I'm using Cygwin in Windows. I use it all the time to write to emulate Linux.

Comment: I tried on Cygwin and if you use UNIX File Format it works

Comment: So let me see if I do it right. 1. I wrote the code in notepad 2. I saved it with Script.sh (it was .txt before) 3. I run the script using ./Script.sh. Do I need to change the file type for Script.sh, or add any packages to cygwin?

Comment: When you save your file choose 'Save as' and change the file format o the encoding.

Comment: Okay. So I had to install VIM and to encode the text to UNIX. Now I can run it, I guess. But when I type ./Script.sh nothing happens. What I understand from the code is that it would write \begin{figure}... for all the png files, right?

Comment: Okay. It was my mistake... I forgot about the ./ which goes one folder back. Now I have a new.tex file that has the commands. It's a bit different than what I wanted, but it's certainly a very useful tool! I will use it meanwhile. Thank you very much, Arianna!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47176/discussion-between-arianna-and-paul).

Answer (score 4):

You can use TeXstudio. Simply drag and drop the image into it. Also for the first time you may need to pre-set some parameters in the wizard.

If the number of images is very high. You may also write some script to import all the images at once using javascript in TeXstudio.

Comment: You mean "TexStudio"?

Comment: Okay. I looked for it. It's an editor, but this also requires that I extract the picture, put it in MSpaint and then take the path and copy-paste the image in the editor. I just did that and it works also with TexMaker (thanks for the advice thought! I didn't know about this)

Comment: I would like to take it from the clipboard somehow.

Comment: in texstudio you may write a javascript macro which would paste from clipboard. Then assign a shortcut to it for the ease of use. but writing macro needs a little work too:).

Comment: Okay. So it is possible. Can one do the same in TeXMaker?

Comment: The macro section in texmaker is not as handy as texstudio and I didn't work with it. Also, it uses another name instead of macro. Totally, I'm advising texstudio for this kind of batch processing

Comment: Okay. I will install TexStudio now. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: see http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html section  4.5.3

Comment: Okay. I found a hint -- editor.paste(); paste clipboard contents --

Comment: I have checked and it was just possible in texstudio last version (2.11.2). I "copied" the image in the pdfxchange then pasted in the texstudio  (ctrl+c, ctrl+v). It asked for where to save. then put the needed commands.

Comment: In Windows, you can simply grab part of your screen with Windows+S, then paste in TexStudio. This is an absolute game changer when doing bibliography work for example.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer by Arianna Angeletti, if the images are in separate subfolders inside a parent folder, then the following bash script will create a text file with latex code for all images in each subfolder. This script must be executed inside the parent folder (the parent folder must not contain pictures itself). The latex for inserting images can be formatted as needed. The file names must not include spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Find all directories in a parent folder
read -p "Enter image file extension (jpg, png, pdf, ...) " ext
DIRS=()
for i in * ; do 
  if [[ -d "$i" ]] && DIRS+=("$i") ; then
    echo "$i" 
  fi
done
# Create a latex code for each image in the subfolder 
#and write the latex code in a file figureFileNames.txt
for dir in "${DIRS[@]}" ; do
   arr=$(cd $dir && ls *.$ext) 
   for f in $arr;
    do
        postfix=".${ext}"
        f=$f
        f=${f%"$postfix"}
        echo '
        \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{'$f'}
        \end{figure}' >> $dir/figureFileNames.txt
    done 
done
```