# Is there a way to import all figures from a folder?

Tags: macros, floats, folders

I collect data into folders that each contain a number of pdf figures. What would be very useful is a latex code that could automatically import and arrange all figures in some standard way. This would save time in manually copying and pasting all filenames. The arrangement could be simple, e.g. place all figures vertically one beneath the other with some fixed scaling parameter.

Does latex or any extension of it provide such functionality?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about the image files, which I understand are contained in separate pdf files. I have two main questions. First, how are the pdf files named? More or less randomly, or in a recognizable scheme such such as `fig001.pdf`, `fig002.pdf`, etc.? Second, in which order should the images be imported and displayed? In alphabetical order be file name, or by some other criterion? If the latter, which sorting criterion should apply? Please advise.

Comment: There is a similar question at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335158/macro-for-copy-paste-image-in-tex-file/335162#335162

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the comment. The pdf files are more or less randomly named, as they come from different sources. The ordering does not matter, so alphabet ordering will do. A basic program for reading and placing images in the tex file will suffice, and I can learn how to tune properties such as ordering later.

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161114/135930) should  solve your problem. (Actually that solution is quite elegant.)